# MS Visual Studio 2008 Professional: How to disable webservers for other projects?

Tags: visual-studio, webserver

I am using visual studio 2008 professional edition. In my solution I have about 8 projects. When I am working on 1 project and I set this one as my startup project and want to debug this one, I get 7 webservers, all with different ports.

I don't want this, I just want that only one webserver is getting started for the project I am debugging. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the project properties in the IDE, there is an "Always Start When Debugging" property. Set this to false, and then only the one you are actually debugging will be started. Select the project node in the Solution Explorer, and look in the Properties window.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "configuration manager" to disable the projects that you don't wnat to debug.

Comment: I can't find a disable option in the configuration manager. I only see Debug, Release, <new> and <edit> in the dropdwon list.